# Symfony cache:pool:clear fails when using Redis Cluster

Tags: symfony, redis, redis-cluster

I am trying to migrate my symfony app on Redis Cluster. I created a cluster on a machine for testing purposes and connected to it.
Now everything works but when I try to clear cache for a specific pool I randomly get this error.
**Failed to clear the cache: Unable to send INFO command to specific node**

I am not familiar with Redis Cluster so I don't really know what to try. When I run

```
php bin/console cache:pool:clear my_pool
```

sometimes will work and sometimes won't.

Comment: I have the same problem, but without any errors. It just says that everything went fine, but no effect.